# Run several jobs parallelly and Efficiently

Tags: linux, parallel-processing

OS: Cent-OS

I have some `30,000` jobs(or Scripts) to run. Each job takes 3-5 Min. I have `48 CPUs(nproc = 48)`. I can use `40 CPUs to run 40 Jobs` parallelly. please suggest some script or tools can handle 30,000 Jobs by running each 40 Jobs parallely.

What I had done:

- I created 40 Different folders and executed the jobs parallely by creating a shell script for each directory.
- I want to know better ways to handle this kind of jobs next time.

Comment: Write a single script whose job is to distribute the 30,000 jobs by forking up to 40 processes. This parent script will wait for child process to finish and move on to next job by forking a new process. At any time, you can have up to 40 child processes.

Comment: You now have 40 folders holding "files?" for each job, right? Why don't you use one folder named "queue/" to hold all the files, and your script that runs a job will "move one file from the folder queue/ to folder working/ and work on this job; upon finish move the file to folder done/"? In this way the number of script you starts = number of concurrency; You can see what's on queue, working, and done. When you need to start again, just move all the files back to "queue/" folder. You can also add more jobs when its still in the middle of processing or remove jobs not start yet.

Comment: Note: In your job processing script when it 'moves' the file its better to move it to folder "working/" with its pid ($$) appended in the filename and check that the moved file is really holding its pid (in the filename). This is a simple way to handle locking because the filesystem will 'move' the file in atomic way, with no need about semaphore nor locking.

Comment: @KenCheung forking is required to implement your suggestion.

Comment: Oh... yes. Indeed I have something similar and I have my scripts start using /etc/inittab (CentOS 5) and it sleeps when there's no file in the queue/ folder.

Comment: @KenCheung Will it it be possible to share on pastebin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Mark Setchell says: GNU Parallel.

```
find scripts/ -type f | parallel
```

If you insists on keeping 8 CPUs free:

```
find scripts/ -type f | parallel -j-8
```

But usually it is more efficient simply to use `nice` as that will give you all 48 cores when no one else needs them:

```
find scripts/ -type f | nice -n 15 parallel
```

To learn more:

- Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1
- Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
  with love you for it.

Comment: But will it give only 48 jobs or it will submit all 30K jobs ?

Comment: It will run 1 job per cpu core until all 30K jobs are done. If you have more questions, I recommend you watch the intro video and walk through the tutorial first: It will clear up most questions.

Answer (score 2):

I have used `REDIS` to do this sort of thing - it is very simple to install  and the CLI is easy to use.

I mainly used `LPUSH` to push all the jobs onto a "queue" in REDIS and `BLPOP` to do a blocking remove of a job from the queue. So you would `LPUSH` 30,000 jobs (or script names or parameters) at the start, then start 40 processes in the background (1 per CPU) and each process would sit in a loop doing `BLPOP` to get a job, run it and do the next.

You can add layers of sophistication to log completed jobs in another "queue".

Here is a little demonstration of what to do...

First, start a Redis server on any machine in your network:

```
./redis-server &    # start REDIS server in background
```

Or, you could put this in your system startup if you use it always.

Now push 3 jobs onto queue called jobs:

```
./redis-cli         # start REDIS command line interface
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> lpush jobs "job1"
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> lpush jobs "job2"
(integer) 2
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> lpush jobs "job3"
(integer) 3
```

See how many jobs there are in queue:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> llen jobs
(integer) 3
```

Wait with infinite timeout for job

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> brpop jobs 0
1) "jobs"
2) "job1"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> brpop jobs 0
1) "jobs"
2) "job2"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> brpop jobs 0
1) "jobs"
2) "job3"
```

This last one will wait a LONG time as there are no jobs in queue:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> brpop jobs 0
```

Of course, this is readily scriptable:

Put 30,000 jobs in queue:

```
for ((i=0;i<30000;i++)) ; do
    echo "lpush jobs job$i" | redis-cli
done
```

If your Redis server is on a remote host, just use:

```
redis-cli -h <HOSTNAME>
```

Here's how to check progress:

```
echo "llen jobs" | redis-cli
(integer) 30000
```

Or, more simply maybe:

```
redis-cli llen jobs
(integer) 30000
```

And you could start 40 jobs like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0;i<40;i++)) ; do
    ./Keep1ProcessorBusy  $i &
done
```

And then `Keep1ProcessorBusy` would be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Endless loop picking up jobs and processing them
while :
do
    job=$(echo brpop jobs 0 | redis_cli)
    # Set processor affinity here too if you want to force it, use $1 parameter we were called with
    do $job
done
```

Of course, the actual script or job you want run could also be stored in Redis.

---

As a totally different option, you could look at `GNU Parallel`, which is [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html). And also remember that you can run the output of `find` through `xargs` with the `-P` option to parallelise stuff.

Comment: Any tutorial on Redis for this job would be very helpful.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a pretty specific example that may help you see how simple it is.

Comment: +1 for showing me various options. I am using parallel for the jobs. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute those scripts, Linux will internally distribute those tasks properly amongst available CPUs. This is upon the Linux task scheduler. But, if you want you can also execute a task on a particular CPU by using `taskset` (see `man taskset`). You can do it from a script to execute your 30K tasks. Remember in this manual way, be sure about what you are doing.

Comment: I assume the question implies he didn't want all 30K jobs to run concurrently. Assign processor affinity using taskset didn't implies the job will execute one by one. They will run together like the day we have only one CPU (core) on Linux - multitasking.

Comment: taskset affines a particular task to a specific CPU and what I meant is affine all those task to the available CPUs and schedule them in round robin fashion and I also warned him about it. I just told him about his available option, I didn't insist.

Comment: I do not see how this is useful for the job.

Comment: @aravindramesh You've failed to understand.

Comment: Let me try, whenever you run your scripts, it's a new process. Linux task scheduler is responsible for making decisions about how your task will get cpu ie which task will get which CPU it's upon task scheduler, scheduler also contains load balancer, which makes sure no CPUs remains idle, whenever a CPU becomes idle it pulls tasks from other busy CPUs, in this way Linux offers best throughput. Just run them all.Now, if you thinking of splitting them up by 40 task at once, you can do so, but it's not strictly required.But, if you really want it, then you can take help of taskset.Hope you got it