# How do I terminate GNU parallel without killing running jobs?

Tags: linux, bash, process, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I'm running a bunch of shell scripts like
`parallel -a my_scripts bash`
and at some point I decided I've run enough of them and would like to stop spawning new jobs, and simply let all the existing jobs finish. Put another way, I want to kill the parent process without killing the children.

There seems to be [ways of controlling termination when first launching  GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Termination) (for example if I know in advance I only want to run `x` jobs, then I can use `--halt now,success=x` argument), but I couldn't find how to control GNU parallel when it is already running.

Sure I can just `CTRL+C` to kill parallel, and rerun the jobs that were aborted, but I thought there might be a smarter way.

Comment: There may be a way to do it with **GNU Parallel**, but another option might be to use Redis like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/22220082/2836621

Comment: **Task Spooler** may be another possibility... http://www.ubuntugeek.com/task-spooler-personal-job-scheduler.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Update:

If you have a new version of parallel `>= 20190322`: as per @Bowi's comment, "since 2019, it is no longer `SIGTERM`, it's `SIGHUP` instead:

```
kill -HUP $PARALLEL_PID
```

`SIGTERM` now terminates the children without letting them finish."

See:

- https://superuser.com/questions/1660301/gnu-parallel-is-behaving-differently-on-sigterm-in-two-cygwin-installation
- http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/NEWS#n687

### Original answer:

I figured it out. The answer is to simply send `SIGTERM` to the parent `parallel` process (just `kill`ing its PID will do). `parallel` then responds with the following (in this case I have 4 jobs running):

```
parallel: SIGTERM received. No new jobs will be started.
parallel: Waiting for these 4 jobs to finish. Send SIGTERM again to stop now.
```

I dug it out of the man page:

> COMPLETE RUNNING JOBS BUT DO NOT START NEW JOBS
> If you regret
> starting a lot of jobs you can simply break GNU parallel, but if you
> want to make sure you do not have half-completed    jobs you should
> send the signal SIGTERM to GNU parallel:
>
> killall -TERM parallel
>
> This will tell GNU parallel to not start any new jobs, but wait
> until the currently running jobs are finished before exiting.

Comment: SIGTERM is very different from SIGKILL. Please fix your answer. SIGKILL will not do what you want.

Comment: Please let us know if you feel how it could have been documented better, so it would have been easier for you to find.

Comment: @OleTange thanks for making this amazing tool available. Perhaps this could be mentioned in the `Termination` section of the [tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Termination), given its common use case? That's the first search result when I googled "GNU parallel terminate".

Comment: **Note**: Since 2019, it is no longer `SIGTERM`, it's `SIGHUP` instead. `SIGTERM` now terminates the children without letting them finish. https://superuser.com/q/1660301/662242

Answer (score 0):

**Small addition if you use parallel inside a simple script:**
If you use parallel (<= 20190322) in a simple script.sh that looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $(dirname $0)

seq -w 0 $(($1-1)) | parallel -j+0 --progress ./something.exe {}
```

you can look up the PID of the child process of script.sh (using `pgrep -P $scriptsh_pid`) and then use

```
kill -TERM $child_process_pid
```

If I only run script.sh in my shell, `killall -TERM perl` also works.