# Processing tasks in multiple processes with a managing application managing the heap of processes

Tags: asynchronous, parallel-processing, distributed-computing, application-pool, task-queue

Is there a standard name for this kind of design. and any existing frameworks in .net to make use of.

Multiple Process.exe are running in the server. There will be a ProcessPoolManager which is responsible for spawning these exes on a need basis. client(s) will send tasks to a queue. PoolManager reads the tasks queue and have them processed in the invoked process.exe and put response back into the queue. and client will get async response from queue when there is a response available.

Do you know what kind of design is this. and how to achieve it with any existing frameworks.
[image: Distributed Processing]

Comment: I try to avoid Windows, but I would suggest Redis would do this easily. Multiple clients can push jobs into a Redis queue and workers can pop jobs off the queue and submit results to another queue. Think of Redis as a *”data structure server”*.

Comment: Here’s an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/22220082/2836621